# How to obtain multiple custom placeholder content?

Tags: php, regex

In PHP I have a string that can contain any quantity of customer placeholders. In this case I am using '[%' & '%]' as the custom placeholders for each iteration.

If my string is equal to:

```
 "test [%variable1%] test test [%variable2%]"
```

How do I extract the 'variables' so I will have something like this:

```
array(
    [0] => variable1,
    [1] => variable2
);
```

At the moment I have: `\b[\[%][a-z.*][\]%]\b` but I know this is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Use `preg_match_all` function to do a global match.

```
$re = "~(?<=\[%).*?(?=%])~m";
$str = "test [%variable1%] test test [%variable2%]";
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

`(?<=\[%)` positive lookbehind which asserts that the match must be preceeded by `[%` symbols. `(?=%])` asserts that the match must be followed by `%]` symbols. `.*?` will do a non-greedy match of any character zero or more times.

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => variable1
    [1] => variable2
)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jO6zT2/11)

Comment: Thanks very much for a quick response. Worked a treat!

Comment: @Boltonian_Soldier If you've found an answer solves your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the green tick below the voting buttons.

Answer (score 1):

```
$re = "/\\[%(.*?)%\\]/";
$str = "test [%variable1%] test test [%variable2%]"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Regex used:

```
/\[%(.*?)%\]/g
```